# DeferWindowPos weird behaviour

Tags: c++, winapi

This happens with all ActiveX controls. If I reposition an ActiveX control with DeferWindowPos

```
HDWP hdwp = BeginDeferWindowPos(1);
DeferWindowPos(hdwp, m_pActiveX->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL, left, top, width, height, SWP_NOZORDER);
EndDeferWindowPos(hdwp);
```

it goes there **but then moves/resizes to its old rectangle once you click anywhere inside the control**. If I use MoveWindow instead

```
m_pActiveX->MoveWindow(left, top, width, height);
```

this doesn't happen.

It doesn't happen with any other type of control, only with ActiveX controls, but it happens with all of them. I made a test to confirm this, creating a new ActiveX control project and didn't make any changes, and the problem was still there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never got an appropriate answer. I'll try to help out a bit here.

The issue is that MFC hides a lot of the trickiness with hosting an ActiveX control within it's framework. Specifically, if you step into the MoveWindow call, it is not simply a wrapper around the Win32 MoveWindow function. It calls into the OLE Control Container support classes. This basically says, if we have a control site interface, then call COleControlSite::MoveWindow, otherwise call the standard Win32 MoveWindow. The same occurs with several other window functions handled by CWnd etc. For example COleControlSite::SetWindowPos handles hiding/showing the control, then calls COleControlSite::MoveWindow to move it, and then finally calls ::SetWindowPos (with the move/show flags masked out) to handle the rest.

Once within COleControlSite::MoveWindow, you will notice it does several things: it calls SetExtent, updates it's internal m_rect member, and then calls SetObjectRects.

Bypassing these for ActiveX controls using the Win32 API directly (eg via DeferWindowPos) causes some of these crucial steps to be missed. Depending on how your code is layed out, usually you can handle this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What is ***this*** ActiveX control?

Apart from that consider that [DeferWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is meant for positioning multiple windows at the same time.  The concept being you enter the begin statement, change a bunch of window positions for a new layout, then end to actually move and apply the new positions and sizes.

If you aren't updating multiple windows consider using [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Consider also that you may be getting a message to move, resize, or change the windows position while you are deferring.  To prevent this if that is what is happening pass the `SWP_NOSENDCHANGING` flag in each call to `DeferWindowPos` so that it is not sent or handle the message and clear all the bits in the `WINDOWPOS` struct received to prevent unwanted changes.

It is also possible for this call to fail ... are you checking the return value?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I am updating multiple windows, the code I put was simplified and was only for illustration of the problem, not the exact source code. The ActiveX control is a PDF preview control made by Amyuni. DeferWindowPos doesn't fail, it does reposition the window, but after you click on it the window 'jumps' to its old size and position. That's the strange thing, that it gets repositioned, but then it seems to change its position on its own (once you click on it).

Comment: Ah in that case it sounds like possibly the control itself is resetting it's position when gaining focus. You might need to email support at Amyuni to get a definite answer ...

Comment: Hm, it seems the problem is not with Amyuni, the same thing happened when I made a new ActiveX control from the new project wizard in VS. It had the exact same problem. This might be a problem with all ActiveX controls. I wonder what's the difference between my  DeferWindowPos call and MoveWindow, may be I should check what's happening with Spy++

Comment: Hi, I edited my question and included the message logs for the ActiveX control when using DeferWindowPos and MoveWindow.

Comment: Those messages do look oddly out of place at first as you actually get the size and pos changed messages before the move in the case of deferring but that may be part of defer.  Assuming this is to avoid flicker you could consider a memory DC but since it happens with any ActiveX my curiosity is peaked ...

Comment: Now that I know what to look for, I see I'm not the only one who had this problem, someone asked about the same problem at [codeguru](http://codeguru.earthweb.com/forum/showthread.php?t=81570). But nobody has found a solution except using SetWindowPos instead of DeferWindowPos.

Comment: Yeah I tried a test the other day but despite various combination of flags I didn't come up with anything either ... might be worth making a bug report with microsoft and using `SetWindowPos` in the meantime for ActiveX.